# Industrial Engineering Program

Tags: mathematics, industrial-engineering

I am a senior in high school and have been accepted into multiple engineering schools, and the top engineering school I'm looking at is OSU(industrial and systems engineering). I have noticed that there is no Calculus 2 and the only programming class required is an intro to Java. I understand that OSU has an impressive engineering program, but I am unsure what courses will be necessary. Could someone please help me understand what mathematics and programming skills are needed in industrial engineering?

Comment: You can always check [these](https://collegegrad.com/careers/industrial-engineers) kind of informative sites. Also you should keep in mind that it is better to focus your career plans and then decide to improve your skillset accordingly.
And one more think, remember, you are going to be an engineer, maybe you don't need to get calculus (calculator can do that too) but you need to get a way of thinking of engineering.

*eg: I myself as a mechanical engineer, I decided to work in defence industry, so I need to use MATLAB and SOLIDWORKS very efficently due to our analysis needs in sector.

Comment: If you want I can write this as an answer. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [our policy is not to give out academic guidance on the main site](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/368). Try speaking with academic counselors at your current and prospective institutions, asking in our [chat], or looking for an internet discussion forum like [College Confidential](http://talk.collegeconfidential.com/).

Comment: The clue is in the words *industrial and systems* engineering. You won't be taught anything much about the "big four" of Mech, Electrical, Chemical, and Civil, and you certainly won't need to use Matlab or Solidworks. To quote the OSU website, you get courses on stuff like "engineering economics ... quality control, supply chain management and logistics, project management ... workplace and facility design, ergonomics..." etc. If you want to be a project manager, that's fine. If you think "project management" is not quite as exciting as "watching paint dry", pick a different degree!

Answer (score 1):

I am a senior mechanical engineering student at Wilkes University in Pennsylvania, so I know what you mean about trying to understand the mathematics and programming courses required for your degree, i'm still dealing with it now as it is.

When you are looking at a program, different schools have different names for different things, so for example at my school you have calc 1, calc 2, differential equations (practical applications of both calc 1 and 2), and then multi-variable calculus. OSU might however have my differential equations class as an engineering specific math course such as applications of differential equations in engineering.

this is the same case with the programming class, it might not say programming in *insert language here*, but it might be like our schools linear systems class, which sounds like a math course, but was a MATLAB programming class on specifically how to solve calculus problems using a program that you design yourself.

mathematics skills are important and if you feel that it's even more important for you to focus in something because you wan to go into a specific industry, you can take a minor in something, or just take a class because it never hurts. The most important thing that i have learned at my internship that I've been working at for the past 2 years is that you need to adapt and learn whatever material is relevant to your current problem. if there's a formula or a concept you don't know or don't understand, don't be afraid to ask your peers, supervisor or even someone on the internet (hi there). also you might be able to find a research study or a book dealing with that specific topic that could help you understand what your trying to do, and who knows you might even learn something else in the long run, which could help you in the future.

It's good that your thinking about this now because you've got your entire college career ahead of you, that way if you wan to deviate and possibly explore something you might be interested in, you can do it. I say good on you and good luck with everything you do, and just make sure to read up on the classes so you can understand the main premise of it before you go into it.

Comment: Also its impossible for the university to teach you all you need to know. Their puroose is to teach you enough so you can find out yourself later.